# Can I add a utility sink which utilizes the existing water and drain lines for my washer?

Tags: plumbing

I want to stack the two Kenmore appliances with a stacking kit I can hopefully find at Sears.  I know I will have to partially block the window as well as remove the shelves on the left.

[image: wash & Dryer]

The reason is I want to install a utility sink near to them that can use the washer's water supplies and drain outlet.

I will replace the existing water lines. How can I connect the sink supplies to the utility sink faucet and the sink's drain to the plastic pipe in which the washer drain hose is connected?

Comment: Do you want to use the utility sink exclusively as a laundry room sink or do you envision it as a *general purpose* utility sink (filling large rolling buckets for floor mopping, cleaning muddy rubber boots, washing the dog's bowl, etc.)?

Comment: If all you really want to do is pre-washing of clothes and light use otherwise, you could first consider a 'special' sink that would fit over the washing machine. If the washing machine could support the weight it could rest on the top of the washer, otherwise a supporting framework  would be constructed over the washer.

Comment: What about a special sink (constructed of say polypropylene sheeting) that would fit between the washer and the dryer? It should be easy to plumb the sink drain into the down pipe. Water supply would be flexible lines teed off of the current washing machine supply lines. I'm not up on the code nor do I understand venting requirements, but it looks to me like the washing machine down pipe is higher than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely utilize the existing water and drain lines for this; here is a video from This Old House where they do exactly that:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-tUGX3M6zY

Your case will probably be easier since it's not in the basement.  Richard in the video re-routes some of the copper plumbing there - I'm not experienced enough to tell whether you can avoid that, but I imagine you should be able to get a splitter like this:

[image: splitter]

What you do for the drain is use a Y-fitting:

[image: y fitting]

You will also need a couple other pieces; watch the video and it will show them.

Good luck!